# media queries dando conflito

Tags: media-queries

Gostaria de saber porque essa *Media queries*:

```
   @media (max-width:533px),(max-height:853px) {
    #menu ul {
        left: 15px;
    }

    #menu ul li a{

        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 4px;
    }
    .setas{
        right: 10%;
    }

    #seta-esquerda{
        transform: scale(1);
        right: 85%;

    }

    #seta-direita{
        transform: scale(1);
        left: 40%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(3.9);
    }

    .nomes{
        font-size: 4.3em;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }

    .texto1 {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .image.ico {

        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 175px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .image.ico img {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 80%; 
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        position: absolute;
        left: -180px;
        top: 80%;
        transform:scale(0.8);
        z-index: -200;
    }

    .main .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 3.5em;
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Gabriola;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }



    .main {
        padding: 6em 0 4em 0;
    }



    .main.style2 {
        background-color: #333;
        color:#fff;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        height: 600px;
        opacity: 0.95;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #f80;
        border-top: 15px solid #f80;

    }

    .main.style2{
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        width: 250px;
        height: 50px;
        border:3px solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-top: 30px;   
        border-radius: 6px;
        font-family: Gabriola;
        font-size: 1.7em;

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"]:hover,.jogos-botao{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        transition:0.5s;
    }

}

/*******************************************************************************

                               600x800

********************************************************************************/
@media (min-width:534px) AND (max-width:600px), (max-height:800px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 12%;
    }

    #menu ul li a{

        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 4px;
    }
    .setas{
        right: 9%;
    }

    #seta-direita{
        transform: scale(1);
        left: 85%;

    }

    #seta-esquerda{
        transform: scale(1);
        right: 85%;

    }

    .container > p{
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }

    .image.ico {

        margin-left: 35%;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 90%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 90%; 
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        margin-top: 20%;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }


    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"]:hover,.jogos-botao{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        transition:0.5s;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 330%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .linha-team{
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
} 


/*******************************************************************************

                              600x1024

   *******************************************************************************/
@media (max-width:600px),(min-height:801px) AND (max-height:1024px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 12%;
    }

    #menu ul li a{
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 4px;
    }

    .setas{
        right: 9%;
    }

    #seta-direita{
        transform: scale(1);
        left: 45%;

    }

    #seta-esquerda{
        transform: scale(1);
        right: 50%;
    }

    .botao-circulo{
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    .nomes{
        margin-top: 20%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(4.1);
    }

    .container > p{
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }

    .image.ico {

        margin-left: 36%;
        margin-top: 100px;
        width: 40%;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 90%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 93%; 
    }

    .jogos-nomes{
        font-size: 4em !important;
    }

    .texto-jogos{

        margin-top: 30%;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }


    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"]:hover,.jogos-botao{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        transition:0.5s;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 330%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .linha-team{
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************

                               603x966

  *******************************************************************************/
@media (min-width:601px) AND (max-width:603px){  
    #menu ul {
        left: 12%;
    }

    #menu ul li a{
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 4px;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************

                               768x1024

  *******************************************************************************/
@media (min-width:604px) AND (max-width:768px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 20%;
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 135%; 
    }

    .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 5% !important;
    }

    .texto-jogos{

        margin-top: 15%;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
}


/*******************************************************************************

                               800x1280

  *******************************************************************************/
@media (min-width:769px) AND (max-width:800px),(min-height:1025px) AND (max-height:1280px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 20%;
    }

    #menu ul li a{
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 4px;
    }

    .setas{
        right: 10%;
    }

    #seta-esquerda{
        transform: scale(0.9);
        right: 85%;

    }

    #seta-direita{
        transform: scale(0.9);
        left: 40%;
    }

    .botao-circulo{
        margin-top: 150px;
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(3.9);
    }

    #bg-video{
        height: 100%;
    }

    .nomes{
        font-size: 4.5em;
        margin-top: 450px;
    }

    .texto1 {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .image.ico {
        width: 40%;
        margin-left: 38%;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .image.ico img {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 150%; 
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        position: absolute;
        left: -180px;
        top: 80%;
        transform:scale(0.8);
        z-index: -200;
    }


    .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 5% !important;
    }

    .texto-jogos{

        margin-top: 15%;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
}
```

Esta dando conflito com esta:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) , screen and (min-height: 600px){

    #menu ul {
        left: 26%;
    }
    .nomes{
        margin-top: 200px;
    }

    .botao-circulo{
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    #header {
        height: 100%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(1.8);
    }


    #bg-video{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -50;

    }

    .image.ico {

        margin-left: 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 90%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 175%; 
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }


    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"]:hover,.jogos-botao{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        transition:0.5s;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 330%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .linha-team{
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }



    #footer .copyright {
        left: 38%;
    }
}


@media screen and(min-width:1024px),screen and(min-height: 768px){
    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 250%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 65%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

}


@media screen and (min-width:1280px),screen and(min-height: 800px){
    /*    #fundo-transparente-icones{
            left: -180px;
            top: 85%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }

         #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
            left: -180px;
            top: 265%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }*/

}


@media screen and (min-width:1366px),screen and(min-height: 768px){
    /*    #fundo-transparente-icones{
            left: -180px;
            top: 90%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }

         #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
            left: -180px;
            top: 275%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }*/

    .setas{
        left: 34%;
    }

}


@media screen and (min-width:1440px),screen and(min-height: 900px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 26%;
    } 
}


@media screen and (min-width:1600px),screen and(min-height: 900px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 32%;
    } 

    .setas{
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 40%;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width:1680px),screen and(max-height: 1050px){
    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width:1920px),screen and(min-height: 1080px){


    #menu ul {
        left: 40%;
    }

    .setas{
        left: 46% !important;
    }

    #seta-esquerda{
       right: 80%;
    }

    #seta-direita{
        left: 20%;
    }


    .nomes{
        font-size: 7em;
        margin-top: 400px;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    .texto1{
        margin-left:10%;
    }

    .botao-circulo{
        margin-top: 80px;
        margin-left:55px;
    }



    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 13%;
    }

    #bg-video{
        width: 100%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaleY(1.5);

    }


    .image.ico {
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 90%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 190%; 
    }

    .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 8% !important;
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        margin-top: 250px;
        margin-left: 90px;
    }


    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   

    }

    .main.style2 {
        height: 800px;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 330%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .linha-team{
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }



    #footer .copyright {
        left: 38%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1920px),screen and(min-height: 1200px){
    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 13%;
    }

    #bg-video{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .setas{
        left: 18%;
    }
}
```

Não consigo entender porque essas medidas estão dando conflito e quando começo a colocar mais medidas elas vão bagunçando e já conseguir fazer as medidas de desktop e com os valores mais baixos como esses dois de exemplo eles dão conflito entre eles.

esses são meus links de css:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsivo/tablet.css" media="screen"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsivo/desktop.css" media="screen"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão `max-width`, quer dizer que a largura tem que ser menor ou igual ao valor especificado. O mesmo vale para altura, `max-height`.

Então você está dizendo:

Aplique a regra para quando a tela tenha largura máxima de `533px` ou altura máxima `835px`

```
@media (max-width:533px),(max-height:853px)  {/*...*/}
```

E aplique a regra para quando a tela trnha largura máxima de `600px` ou altura máxima de `800px`

```
@media (max-width:600px), (max-height:800px){/*...*/}
```

Então se a tela tem largura de `500px`, que é menor que `533px` e menor que `600px` ou largura de `768px` que é menor que `835px` e `800px`. Ou seja está dando verdadeiro para as duas regras, então a ÚLTIMA irá prevalecer, pois é assim que funcione para o CSS, a não ser que use `!important` ou o seletor seja mais específico.

Para evitar esse tipo de coisa, use regras "isoladas":

```
@media (max-width:533px),(min-height: 801px) and (max-height:853px)  {/*...*/}

@media (min-width:534px) AND (max-width:600px), (max-height:800px){/*...*/}
```

Para mais detalhes consulte a [documentação da mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries), que é bem completa, porém em inglês. (Espero que não seja um problema.)

Comment: "hmmmm" amigo vou testar isso agora porque isso ai eu não sabia

Comment: amigo eu devo seguir essa mesma lógica para todas as outras medidas que são essas:  533x853, 600x800, 600x1024, 603x966, 768x1024, 800x1280.

um exemplo de como estou fazendo:

media (max-width:533px),(max-height:853px){...}

media (max-width:600px),(min-height:801px) AND (max-height:1024px){...}


media (max-width:600px),(min-height:801px) AND (max-height:1024px){...}

media (min-width:601px) AND (max-width:768px),(max-height:1024px){...}

Comment: Sim @Kirito, uma regra não deve "entrar" dentro da outra, cada bloco de valores deve conter apenas 1 regra...

Comment: amigo segui a logica em todas as medidas de tablet no caso de deu certo porem eu antes havia feito desktop first né e agora ele bagunço inteiro veja as medidas que já havia feito na media queries de desktop:

1024x600, 1024x768, 1280x800, 1366x768, 1440x900, 1600x900, 1680x1050, 1920x1050, 1920x1200.

Aqui está um exemplo da media queries desktop de como eu acabei de fazer seguindo sua explicação e mesmo assim não arrumou:  @media (min-width: 801px) AND (max-width:1024px) ,(max-height: 600px){...}

Comment: Talvez seja esse max-height que esteja bagunçando, se você usar apenas o width não tem como @Kirito?

Comment: vou testar só um instante

Comment: não deu certo amigo vou fazer assim irei editar meu post e colocar todo o meu código tablet que foi feito da forma que você me passou e o do desktop como ele esta ai você poderia ver oque tem de errado

Comment: editei amigo da uma olhada la no meu código

Comment: Então @Kirito, é pelo mesmo motivo, note que o sua altura mínima `min-height: 600px` está dentro da altura máxima `max-height:853px`, ou seja, tem uma regra dentro da outra, então vai prevalecer a última da sequência.

Comment: beleza então a parte de desktop eu apaguei tudo e comecei uma nova veja o seguinte:
@media (min-width: 801px) AND (max-width:1024px) ,(max-height: 600px){...}. 
Essa é a minha primeira media querie do modo desktop estou usando essas medidas e mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: Desculpe @Kirito, mas não vai dar pra te ajudar, fica difícil sem ver o que está acontecendo, da uma olhada naquela documentação, mas o problema é que uma regra está entrando dentro da outra. Tem uma opção de verificar se está landscape ou portrait `and (orientation: landscape)` veja se te ajuda. ;)

Comment: "ok" de qualquer forma muito obrigado pela ajuda viu arcar como resposta porque deu certo na parte de tablet vou abrindo mais tópicos quem sabe não resolva